# How should I go about registering JavaScript that isn't a file?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, customization, wp-register-script, development-strategy

For a plugin I'm creating it generates custom JavaScript that should be executed in the footer of the page. Being that it's custom JavaScript, I can't simply put it in a file and register & enqueue the file. How should I go about Registering and Enqueuing custom JavaScript?

Note: It would be for a Shortcode. The JavaScript would look something like this,

`$("#CustomID").aFunction(withCustomData);`

Again, I need it to be executed in the footer of the page, I can't simply return it in the shortcode.

### Edit 1

The JavaScript is "truly" unique. It takes in parameters from the shortcode itself and may change depending on the time. Again, this is something that is constantly changing and something that should not be put in a file each time it needs to be loaded.

Comment: is the script truly unique for each instance of the shortcode, or is just the data the script operates on unique? if you could give a more detailed example, then you will probably get a better answer.

Comment: @Milo Yes, the script is truly unique and it may change depending on factors for the shortcode. I tried to give more detail and edited my answer, do you have any other questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hook the [`wp_footer`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer) action to output arbitrary JavaScript. This the same action that WordPress uses to output footer enqueued scripts.

Here's an example that encapsulates the shortcode, data, and script output in a class:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WPD_Example
*/

class WPD_Example_Plugin {

    public $data = array();

    function __construct() {
        add_shortcode( 'wpd_example', array( $this, 'shortcode_func' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $this, 'footer_scripts' ), 9999 );
    }

    function shortcode_func( $atts ) {
        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'title' => 'title'
        ), $atts, 'wpd_example' );
        $id = uniqid();
        $this->data[$id] = $atts['title'];
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        return '<div data-id="' . $id . '">' . $atts['title'] . '</div>';
    }

    function footer_scripts() {
        if( !empty( $this->data ) ){
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                if ( undefined !== window.jQuery ) {
                    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                        var myData = <?php echo wp_json_encode( $this->data ); ?>;
                        $.each( myData, function( id, title ) {
                            console.log( id + ' : ' + title );
                        });
                    });
                }
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }

}

$wpd_plugin = new WPD_Example_Plugin;
```

---

**EDIT**

Here's another example that's similar to above, but enqueues a script and passes data via `wp_localize_script` rather than printing js directly to the page. You can access any of this data from the enqueued script in the `wpdScriptData` js object. Read the comments below this answer for an explanation as to why this method is safer.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WPD_Example
*/

class WPD_Example_Plugin {

    public $data = array();

    function __construct() {
        add_shortcode( 'wpd_example', array( $this, 'shortcode_func' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $this, 'footer_scripts' ), 0 );
    }

    function shortcode_func( $atts ) {
        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'title' => 'title'
        ), $atts, 'wpd_example' );
        $id = uniqid();
        $this->data[$id] = $atts['title'];
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wpd-script', plugins_url( '/js/script.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
        return '<div data-id="' . $id . '">' . $atts['title'] . '</div>';
    }

    function footer_scripts() {
        if( !empty( $this->data ) ){
            wp_localize_script(
                'wpd-script',
                'wpdScriptData',
                $this->data
            );
        }
    }

}

$wpd_plugin = new WPD_Example_Plugin;
```

Comment: I upvoted, but IMO if you need jQuery then you need to enqueue it at the header to let it have a chance to load before the relevant code is executed. In this code it will be loaded at the footer and might not be able to load before the code is called. (unless wordpress force it to be loaded in sync, and I am not sure what it does)

Comment: I don't like the `wp_footer` method. Not at less like it has been proposed in this answer.

Comment: @cybmeta I agree that `wp_localize_script` would be better, but it depends on exactly what is being passed, hence my comment asking for clarification (which I'm not entirely satisfied with). Can you outline a case where the above would fail?

Comment: For example, I can enqueue jquery in the footer, which is quite common, with `wp_enqueue_script( "jquery", "..", [...], "...", true )`. How to be sure taht the inline js in footer is loaded after jQuery?. Or I can use a tool for concatenation, minification and async loading before `</body>`, which is also quite common across the web, for example W3TC. Again, how to be sure that the inline js in footer is loaded after jQuery? Just some examples. In the linked question in my comment there are several comments (and answers) about this topic. Of course, I can be wrong.....

Comment: @cybmeta Footer scripts are output on priority 20, that's why I hooked it on priority 9999. I also wrapped the script in a check for the jQuery object, so it will just fail silently. I agree it's not ideal, it's up to the user to decide how dangerous it may be in their case I suppose.

Comment: The issue with footer scripts was just one possible break point that seems to have a easy work around. The other issue with W3TC (or a similar tool) seems to have a more difficult work around, maybe none because it specifically loads the script before `</body>` (if the user configure it to do so). Printing inline js that depends on anohter has so many possible break points that, I think, it is generally accepted that it is a bad practice. But, of course, it's up to the user to decide which solution he/she wants to use. In my opinion, using WordPress dependecies manager is always a gain.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a very big fan of WordPress dependencies manager. I love it. ;)

Comment: @cybmeta - I edited my answer above to include another version which enqueues and localizes a script rather than printing js directly.